# How do improved specs improve running nodes?

Tags: go-ethereum, nodes

It'd be useful to know what exactly having a superior any of these helps with the node:

- CPU
- RAM
- disk speed
- download speed
- upload speed
- others?

For example, [apparently](https://docs.gnosischain.com/node/consensus-layer-validator#lighthouse-client) network speed helps supports more validators

---

I'm trying to determine, for various use cases, what the appropriate node hardware & network configurations would be. Then I can figure what lowest specs I can get away with, as running execution & consensus clients on the min requirements compared to recommended specs would have effects, but I don't know what exactly.

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs on ethereum.org, the recommended specifications for running a node is :

- Fast CPU with 4+ cores
- 16 GB+ RAM
- Fast SSD with 1+TB
- 25+ MBit/s bandwidth

From the above, it's implied that CPU speed has highest priority in improving the running of a node, followed by RAM, then SSD, and finally bandwidth.

See: https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/nodes-and-clients/run-a-node/

Comment: But what exactly does a better CPU/etc help the node do? (i.e. what would the difference of output be between a low CPU node and high CPU node?)

Comment: A higher CPU node can process more transactions, both when they first arrive (in the memory pool) and when they are confirmed within a block in the chain, compared to those of a lower CPU node, in a given amount of time.